# When does meteor recompile .less files

Tags: meteor, less

I am using meteor 1.0.3.1 with nemo64:bootstrap 3.3.1_1 and less 1.0.12. I have created my own .less file to add some (very simple) classes and such to my site.

I found out that when I change .less files, they do not get automatically recompiled. Instead I need to reload the application on the client to get new CSS loaded.

To my understanding this is kind off breaking the Meteor reactive principle but I am not sure whether it is expected with .less files. Can anyone clear it out?

Thanks folks!

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Can you provide a reproduction in the form of an app on github?

Comment: You are right and in case it was not the case. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the reason. I ran into a race condition on the tests I was doing. So there is no real problem. I owe you guys some more details:

I wanted to play a little with sacha:spin meteor package. To do that I created a template which shows some data my app subscribed to. I used then this package to show a spinner while the data was being loaded. So I added {{>spinner}} to the template.

Then when all data was loaded on the client I hide the spinner by adding a my custom 'hide' class into it.

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts',{
    onReady : function(){$('.spinner').addClass('hide');},
    onError : function(){alert('error!!');}
})
```

class

```
.hide {display:none;}
```

So, I think that, sometimes, when the subscribed data is ready on the client the template is not rendered yet, therefore no class can be added to the spinner.

To fix it I just changed the class manipulation code to Template..rendered callback and it worked

```
Template.testTemplate.rendered = function(){
    $('.spinner').addClass('hide');
};
```

So yeah that is the root problem. One thing though that confused me was that if you check in browser source files with developer tools (in Chrome), it seems that CSS files do not get updated there (though the application uses them). So combining one and the other I thought my LESS files were not handled correctly.

Thanks for interests. I hope this helps someone.

Cheers.